# How to implement TableView.insertRows

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am adding pagination to `myTableview` that presents blog posts.  The data source is an array of posts, i.e. `posts = [post]`.

I initially fetch 20 posts. I have a button that fetches the next 20 records.  All of this is working fine.  I can't figure how to insert these new records in the table without calling `reloadData()`.  Can someone explain the following code?  I don't understand what going on with the `indexPaths` on line 2 and 3 below.
On:

```
IndexPath(row:(self.posts.count - 1)
```

Am I passing the last row of the original dataset or the updated one?

```
TableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(row:(self.posts.count - 1), section:0)
TableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
TableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: If you add 20 rows, you have to pass it an array of 20 index paths, one for each new row.

Comment: @Rob, I'm drawing a blank here. So if I add an additional 20 records to the first 20 then the first index path in the [indexPath] array would be row:20, section:0 ?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because `row` values in `IndexPath` are zero-based, the first new row (row 21) would be an `IndexPath` with a `row` of `20` and the last one would have a `row` of `39`, for a total array of 20 new index paths.

Comment: As an aside, you only need `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` if you're doing multiple calls to update cells and you want them all to take place in one update. Since you're only doing one call to `insertRows`, no `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` is needed. It doesn't hurt, but it's just not needed.

Comment: Sorry Rob.. I thought I did!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to add items to your tableview, the value passed to `insertRows` will be an array of index paths for the new rows in your model object:

```
let additionalPosts = ...
posts += additionalPosts

let indexPaths = (posts.count - additionalPosts.count ..< posts.count)
    .map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }

tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .left)
```

So, if you had 20 items in your array, and you add another 20 posts, the `indexPaths` would be:

> [[0, 20], [0, 21], [0, 22], [0, 23], [0, 24], [0, 25], [0, 26], [0, 27], [0, 28], [0, 29], [0, 30], [0, 31], [0, 32], [0, 33], [0, 34], [0, 35], [0, 36], [0, 37], [0, 38], [0, 39]]

Answer (score -1):

```
    let intTempCount = messages.count ?? 0
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()

    messages.append(contentsOf: messageList)

    for index in intTempCount ..< (messages.count ?? 0) {
        let indexPathTobeAddedinTable = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        indexPaths.append(indexPathTobeAddedinTable)
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .bottom)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
```